# Set default value in a FOR LOOP when one ROW SET is smaller than another

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Trying to build out an email based on a few `BuildRowSetFromString` calls, but the email is failing because the `For Loop` code is using the RowCount from one String that has more rows than another `BuildRowSetFromString`.

We've tried to include some conditional content on the Rows, but it's returning an error - likely because the row doesn't exist for the condition to be met.  What we tried:

```
IF IsNull(Row(@devicelinkrows, @i)) THEN 
    SET @devicelink = "null"
  ELSE  
    SET @devicelinkrow = Row(@devicelinkrows, @i)
    SET @devicelink = field(@devicelinkrow,1)             
ENDIF
```

We have content that inserts a link when the value is 'null'.

Is it possible to SET a default when the rowcount is lower for one set versus another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep a single rowcount for the max iterative and want it to be the larger one, you will want to add in some conditionals based on rowcount.

For example:

```
SET @RowcountA = Rowcount(@RowsetA)
SET @RowcountB = Rowcount(@RowsetB)

SET @RowcountCompare = SUBTRACT(@RowcountA, @RowcountB)

IF @RowcountCompare > 0 THEN

    SET @LargerRowset = @RowcountA

ELSE

    SET @LargerRowset = @RowcountB

ENDIF

FOR @i = 1 TO @LargerRowset DO

    IF @i <= @RowcountA THEN

        SET @ItemARow = Row(@RowsetA, @i)
        SET @ItemA = field(@ItemARow,1)          

    ELSE

        SET @ItemA = ''

    ENDIF

    IF @i <= @RowcountB THEN

        SET @ItemBRow = Row(@RowsetB, @i)
        SET @ItemB = field(@ItemBRow,1)          

    ELSE

        SET @ItemB = ''

    ENDIF

NEXT @i
```

This will make it so it will not do the Row and Field lookup if the iterative (@i) is greater than the row count - preventing the error.

Comment: The logic...It's working!  Gortington, I owe you on more beer.  Keep this up and I'll need to send a keg soon!

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how the two rowsets are related. 
If you think of your two rowsets as two rows in a datasheet, underneath each other - Are there gaps in your second rowset at random points throughout the column?

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,gap,2,2,2,2,gap
```

this is pretty hard to solve. You'd want an array, which a "RowsetFromString" never is.

Options I see:

Either fill the gaps with "some value", then you can simply write an if / else check to handle "some value" accordingly inside your loop.

Or sort both rowsets somehow, so the gaps are at the end:

Assuming that the order in both is the same and the only missing rows are sorted towards the end of your second column:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,gap,gap
```

One approach could be to loop through your rowsets, and write them into a data extension side by side.  Then you can do lookups and empty checks for pairs. This essentially acts as an array.

```
1 2
1 2
...
1 gap
1 gap
```

Another approach would be to use rowcount() on both sorted rowsets.  Compare the two counts, and use only the smaller rowcount in a first for loop. 
This will produce all your pairs.
Then, from the the smaller rowcount + 1, iterate through the rest of the records (the ones without a match) to the higher rowcount, just setting defaults instead of empty values, or producing an error.

Comparing rowcounts is a simple subtract and logical test.

```
IF Subtract(rowCount(rowset1),rowCount(rowset2) > 0 THEN

ENDIF
```